# Can this space retract to its boundary?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider $D^2$, remove two open balls from the interior, and glue two copies of $S^1$'s along the boundaries of these two holes, according to the maps $z \mapsto z^p$, and $z \mapsto z^q$ for distinct primes $p,q$. For example, I'm attaching a picture of how it might look for the case $p=2$, $q=3$:
[image]

Can this space be retracted to it's boundary? I have heard this mentioned in passing by someone, but never understood why. Is this even true?

Comment: There is no retraction since the boundary circle is homologically trivial in your space.

Comment: What do you mean by the boundary of the space?